# Rest API - Which method for creating methods on init but later not?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have case that I'm tracking habits of user and displaying it to him table with every day of month status.

If user won't login and check it as done then records for that day won't be created.

My question is to get records I can't use GET method because I'm mutating resource on init (I'm creating records for that day).
I cannot create this records everyday because I think this could be a huge waste of resources if user woudn't login for 1year and also scheduling such event would use a lot of resources.

So, GET method will return existing records (without updating collection) and I should use PUT/PATCH to get records till today?

Comment: You can use Patch for partial update.

Comment: That's just lazy evaluation, the request is still idempotent. The user shouldn't have to make a different request just because of a performance optimisation you may or may not be making behind the scenes.

Comment: Yeah, so 
GET = get deprecated table
PATCH = to update table till today and get it? (Structure of path is as for GET and body is empty)

Comment: No; the client isn't actually creating or updating the resource, the server is doing that as a side effect, so PUT/POST/PATCH *aren't* appropriate. Think about the *second* time the client wants to know the data, should it have to make a different request because the creation has already happened?

Comment: Also a PATCH with an empty body means, if anything, "no change".